# Hibernate query where item in list

Tags: hibernate, hql

Can anyone suggest the correct syntax for a where clause using `in`
applied to a list? The following query in an .hbm file generates a parse
exception:

```
<query name="Nutrient.findNutrients1">
    <![CDATA[from Nutrient as nutrient where nutrient.id in elements(?)]]>
</query>
```

The exception follows:

> PARSER.reportError(56) | line 2:95:
>   expecting IDENT, found '?'
>   SessionFactoryImpl.(395) | Error
>   in named query:
>   Nutrient.findNutrients1
>   org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException:
>   expecting IDENT, found '?' near line
>   2, column 95 [        from Nutrient as
>   nutrient where nutrient.id in
>   elements(?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the `elements` part of your query:

```
<query name="Nutrient.findNutrients1">
    <![CDATA[from Nutrient as nutrient where nutrient.id in (:ids)]]>
</query>
```

And invoke it like this:

```
List<Long> vals = Arrays.asList(1L, 2L);

Query q = session.getNamedQuery("Nutrient.findNutrients1");
q.setParameterList("ids", vals);
List<Nutrient> result = q.list();
```

Comment: Thanks for this. However, I'm not sure how to use named parameters in a query defined in an .hbm file - I thought you needed to do this through the session... Do you know if it can be done via .hbm?

Comment: @Greg You can use either positional or named parameters in named queries. But that's not the important part anyway. I can remove it if you prefer :)

Comment: @Pascal Rather than remove, would you mind adding a little bit to show how to pass in the named parameter in this context?

Comment: @Gred I should have done that in my initial answer. See my update.

Comment: @Pascal Sorry to be needy here, but would you also show a version of the query that uses positional parameters? (I'm sure I'm doing something silly, but it's just not parsing as I expect it to)

Comment: @Greg Actually, there is no `Query#setParameterList(int, Collection)`, you'll have to use a named parameter.